# Name with dashes map to action parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to have dashes in the name of an element and map it to a parameter in an action, without writing a new `IModelBinder`?

```
 @Html.DropDownList("my-list")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were calling the action with jquery you could map it to a correct parameter on the client side. eitherwise I'd think you'd have to write a custom model binder.